# How to completely remove Firefox and all related data from MacOS 12?

Tags: macos, firefox

I removed:

```
Applications/Firefox.app
~/Library/Application\ Support/Mozilla
~/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox
~/Library/Caches/Mozilla
```

And then reinstalled Firefox, but it still has data from before. Does somebody know an exhaustive list of where Firefox stores data on MacOS 12?

Answer (score 1):

Try [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (Freeware). Saves trying to find everything yourself.

It finds these…

[image]

…and can remove any or all with a single click.

Note: Don't use it to uninstall anything that needed a true installer in the first place. They don't follow the same rules & will need an appropriate app-specific uninstaller. AppCleaner works well for 'standard' apps that drag & drop to Applications from a Disk Image.